# Modifying styling on infowindows (Carto)?

Tags: carto, infowindow

I'm working on a map with lots of infowindows, many of which are too tall for the embed window, which requires some awkward scrolling in order to exit out of any given card. Is it possible to modify the styling of the infowindow on Carto to make the pop-up cards horizontal? Or to change the dimensions of the map such that it is square rather than widescreen?

https://rszypko.carto.com/builder/050f7b58-0dae-11e7-86df-0ee66e2c9693/embed

Answer (score 1):

There is a slider to change the window size up to `400px` on the POPUP tab as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Unfortunately it doesn't quite fix the issue. The problem is that many of the pop up boxes are too tall, and the embed window cuts the top of them off. So I was wondering if there was a way to arrange the card horizontally so that the image is on the side of the text, rather than above (therefore reducing the chance that a user would have to click and drag the map up in order to read the entire pop-up they just clicked on).

Comment: Unfortunately, that type of customization is not available in BUILDER. You can still use CARTO.js with `createLayer` method and a custom infowindow as explained in the [documentation](https://carto.com/docs/tutorials/custom_interactivity).